# PhoneGap Installation : npm command not found

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I have a Mac OS X version 10.9.1. I tried installing PhoneGap via the command line

`$ sudo npm install -g phonegap`

BUT i get the following error:

`sudo: npm: command not found`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the Node Package Manager installed on your system.

https://npmjs.org/

This requires you to install Node.js

Answer (score 1):

**The phonegap is installed using the node package manager(NPM)**, *the package is not available on your pc* , so you need to install it.

use this command to install,

> sudo apt-get install npm

It will fix the issue. then do the installation command .

Answer (score 1):

If your npm isn't installed in /usr/local/bin, you must create a symbolic link for it first.

```
$ sudo ln -s $(which npm) /usr/local/bin/npm
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Answer (score 0):

If u already install Node package and still getting the same error, then check the  bin (/usr/local/bin) folder permission.

If you don't have enough permission then change folder the permission using below command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin
```

I have shared my whole experience while installing the phone gap is here

https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/ios/phonegapinstalltionwithnodejs

Answer (score 0):

In one of the answers to the question suggesting chmod -R 777 - I must warn against using.

chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin

This means that all files in bin and its subdirectories will be readable, writable and executable by the whole world.


If one did so by accident, as minimum change it to 

 
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin

and then think closer about how the permissions should be set after that.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting this error because you do not have NODE packages installed in your machine. Download and install it before running npm install command from below link https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).